# My device is not showing up in "Android Device Chooser" suddenly

Tags: android, android-emulator

i am using my samsung galaxy3 device for testing my apps from last two months. It is working fine. 
But suddenly from this morning when i connected my device to my system it is not showing up in the "Android Device chooser" window.
I have checked, USB debug mode is in checked state only in my device.

Can anybody guess the problem. It is little urgent.

Thanks,
Nehatha

Comment: Have you tried to kill and restart the adb server?

Comment: Yes, i have tried that...but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my device is working after "Factory data Reset".

Thanks you all for your suggestions, even those suggestions not worked for me, I came to know about other useful.

Thank You.

Comment: I have debug set to true, and just did a factory reset. Nothing.. I've rebooted my computer, and my android.  Nothing??  Anyone got anything else.

Answer (score 9):

Use a shell of some sort (Run -> cmd) and browse to the /platform-tools/ directory inside the place you installed the Android SDK Tools.

Shut down Eclipse, unplug your device and try running:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Plug it back in and run

```
adb devices
```

If you can see it, good. Now run:

```
adb logcat -c
adb logcat
```

This will flush the current logcat output and then show the logcat output in the shell as it updates (do something on the device and the log will update). Stop it with Ctrl-C and restart Eclipse.

This has helped for me sometimes.

Also, rebooting helps.

I have another similar issue over here which I haven't found an answer to yet: [Device going offline randomly (and appearing multiple times as offline) in Eclipse - fixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154847/device-going-offline-randomly-and-appearing-multiple-times-as-offline-in-eclips)

Hope some of it helps.

Comment: Maybe try to reinstall your USB drivers? Remove them and install 'em again from the Google USB Driver list. Not much else to do... :/

Comment: Hi Klaus, it is working after factory reset.. anyway thank for your suggestions.

Comment: You mention USB drivers.  The google USB driver list refers to several OEM's... What if mine isn't listed?

Comment: this response has saved me twice now in the past few days so thanks for that. Any idea what is happening to require this fix?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I figured out the solution for me.

1. On the home screen of your device choose Menu > Settings > Applications > Development.
2. Make sure that ‘USB debugging’ is checked.

Hope it will help someone :)

Comment: This is a duplicate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041904/run-android-apps-on-hardware-device-from-android-studio-by-usb

Answer (score 0):

close the emulator then restart eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I have restarted eclipse, emulater, entire system and the device too but not luck..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, what worked for me was switching to "connected as camera" mode instead of "connected as media device" from the USB options menu, then performing Klaus's solution (kill server, start server).