# Run Android apps on hardware device from Android Studio by USB

Tags: android, device, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am developing apps in Android Studio and I can run them in the virtual device succesfully. However running the apps on my own device (Samsung S3 GT-I9300) doesn't work.

Based on the documentation of Google (http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) I have tried this:

1. In the application tag of the AndroidManifest.xml I have added: `android:debuggable="true"`.
2. Installed the latest OEM driver from the Samsung Website

In the Android Studio I changed in the Edit Configurations the target device into USB device. But I constantly get this message:

> Waiting for device.
>
> USB device not found

I also have installed Kies software from Samsung and with this software I can connect my phone by USB. I have also tried `adb devices` in `\sdk\platform-tools`, but no devices are listed.

Comment: First time it will always selected only emulator options http://stackoverflow.com/a/16585266/1012284

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have solved the problem! I didn't enable USB debugging in the settings.

Comment: Thank you for this. To clarify, the solution is to enable USB Debugging on the Android device. I had enabled Developer Options on my phone by tapping 7 times but then didn't go into the options to enable USB Debugging.

Comment: And for those that don't know how to enable USB debugging see http://www.wugfresh.com/faq/6/

Answer (score -1):

For Mac user, just **restart your mac** after installing android studio. Check Choose a running device at Device Chooser interface, you can see your device in the list.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html