# in android studio my phone in device chooser not showing

Tags: android, android-studio

The device chooser is not showing my plugged phone , I tried Samsung note3 and note 4 , both of them are not showing in android studio. it was showing before , then i dont know why sudently not working . I tried this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178014/my-device-is-not-showing-up-in-android-device-chooser-suddenly) but didnt work. I have sdk 24.3.4 should I update to 24.4 ?

in first phone(note 3) yes  usb debugging is authorized, it was working normal before , in note4 no I didnt activate debug mode

Comment: Can you confirm that usb debugging is enabled? Can you confirm that usb debugging is authorized?

Comment: Do you have Developer options enabled on those devices?

Comment: Also, please include `adb devices` command output.

Comment: @MariusKaunietis as I add in the edit yes in my first phone the debugging is authorize(developer options) and please can you explain how to show you the ocmmand output

Comment: I assume you use Windows. First, locate a file named `adb.exe`, which should be in `<sdk>/platform-tools/`. Then right click in the directory and choose "open command prompt window here", then type in `adb.exe devices` (not sure if you need .exe, I hardly ever use windows for anything other than gaming).

Comment: @MariusKaunietis I richt clicked on it but i didnt have open command prompt window here , by the way I tried another phon and the degugin is authorised but still the adb not reading it

Comment: Try these steps to open Command Prompt window: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/27778-open-command-window-here.html

Comment: do you want to past all the result ? btw if i run adb devices its not shoing anything

Comment: I have done some development work on a Samsung Galaxy Note, and I noticed that sometimes I had to fudge around with the phone to get it to recognize the USB connection.  This could be why sometimes it seems to be working for you, but others it does not.

Comment: so what should I do to start working ? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: What worked for me was unplugging the USB cable from the phone and then plugging it back in.  If this works for you, I will post it as a formal answer.

Comment: i wish if this is a solution, no unfortunetly it didnt work @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: The Note phone should show a popup dialog box asking you to OK connecting it as a USB device.  If you don't see this, then it's not connected.  This is not a problem with Android Studio, despite the appearance of it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it never popup on my phone to ask if usb to connect , even before when it was working it didnt ask that. when i connect it to usb, i can access images and other thing in my phon

Comment: Accessing images and "other things" may use a totally different driver than the one needed for deploying apps on your phone from Android Studio.  In any case, I may not be able to help you any further.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am installing the driver from samsung http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117 i dont know if i have any other choice

Comment: @Moudiz General comment: It's _really_ bad form to go around peppering everyone's questions and answers with many comments.  Try to avoid this in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure the usb driver for the phone is installed correctly,you can check in device manager.

Here is a [link to the Samsung technical spec](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117) for the USB driver.

Comment: I can access the images and folders of the phone , does that mean its is installed correctly ?, also in the device manager I didnt notice any unistalled devices

Comment: if there are no errors in device manager then the device is probably properly installed. this happens to me from time to time and what i do to resolve the issue is turn off developer options on my device, restart android studio and then turn developer options back on.

Comment: go to the devices settings and find developer options then there should be a toggle button to turn the options on/off

Comment: add this link in your question http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install sw usb driver on my computer with win7, it helped.
according this
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

Comment: Please, at least summarize the main steps taken from that url instead of just copy/pasting a link to an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link from offical site http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Nearly supports all the devices that i have tested.

Comment: Supposing you are using Windows OS for development. Check the Device Manager by right clicking My Computer and then Manage..Check the drivers are installed or not.